# IIS rewrite and redirect to different site on same server based on server variable value

Tags: iis

I would like to know - is it possible to rewrite incoming url to IIS and redirect it to different web application on the same server ?

For example :

Original URL : 
www.test.com/api/test

Desired URL after rewrite : 
www.test2.com/api/{SERVER_VAR_VALUE}/test

Thank you

Comment: What server variable are you talking about? Reverse proxy can do so much https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing

Comment: basically  I have the same URL coming from client, example www.test.com/api/ and based on some condition that can be configured on web server that can be routed to www.test.com/api/ or www.test2.com/api/{condition value}/